# Can a diagonalizable matrix have entries that are not on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the real matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    2& 0 & 0 \\
    0      & 2& 0  \\
    1      & 1 &3
\end{bmatrix}

Is A diagonalizable? If so, find the matrix P by which you need to conjugate to produce a diagonal matrix

I have been trying to solve this problem first I worked out the eigenvalues as 2 and 3 and the eigenvectors as $(−1, 0, 1)^T, (0, −1, 1)^T$ for 2 and $(0,0,1)^T$ for 3.

Then I took these as a basis B and tried to work out $_{B}[A]_{B}={_{B}[id]_{e}}{_{e}[A]_{e}}{_{e}[id]_{B}}$ where e is the standard basis of $R^3$ but as this is meant to give $D=P^{-1}AP$, $_{B}[A]_{B}$ should give a diagonal matrix for D but I keep getting 
\begin{bmatrix}
    3& 1 & 1 \\
    0      & 2& 0  \\
    1      & 0 &2
\end{bmatrix}
Which is not a diagonaal matrix, where am I going wrong?

I also got P as
\begin{bmatrix}
    0& -1 & 0 \\
    0      & 0& -1  \\
    1      & 1 &1
\end{bmatrix}
which is apparently correct.

Comment: I get eigenvectors $(−1, 0, 1)^T, (-1,1,0)^T$ for 2 and $(0,0,1)^T$ for 3.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B2,0,0%7D,%7B0,2,0%7D,%7B1,1,3%7D%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P=\begin{bmatrix}
    0& -1 & 0 \\
    0      & 0& -1  \\
    1      & 1 &1
\end{bmatrix}$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2& 0 & 0 \\
    0      & 2& 0  \\
    1      & 1 &3
\end{bmatrix}$.

So $P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1& 1 & 1 \\
    -1      & 0& 0  \\
    0      & -1 &0
\end{bmatrix}$. Then you get:

$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}
    3& 0 & 0 \\
    0      & 2& 0  \\
    0      & 0 &2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you I've just realised I my $P^{-1}$ was wrong as I had worked it out from changing the basis as above and one of the 1's was in the wrong place!